# IIS 7.5 Python2 PySimpleSoap Timeout

Tags: python, timeout, pysimplesoap

I am running a Python(v2.7.8) web application (with) on IIS 7.5 (via wsgi).
In that application I request an other server with pySimpleSOAP.
Sometimes when the action on the requested server takes to long, a timeout error occurs.

Does anybody know how to change that behaviour ?
How to increase the accepted amount of time ?

I already increased the IIS timeout

Comment: Is there a Python traceback somewhere in the logs? It's important to know which kind of timeout occurs (ISS vs. Python vs. pysimplesoap). If it's Python (socket) timeout you should check the docs for Python's socket module.

Comment: in the logfile I discovered "error: [Errno 10054] Eine vorhandene Verbindung wurde vom Remotehost geschlossen". I increased the remote-hosts IIS-Timeout. It does work now.